# ASP.NET MVC passing an ID in an ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

how can I pass an id through actionlink without this being shown through the url?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id}) |
```

The URL appears to me the next picture form:

```
http://localhost:49723/UsersAdmin/Edit?id=c070d5f8-57ce-4714-a3e7-2b293b1a3e12
```

was supposed to pass the parameter id to the edit page without which this was shown in the url.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thats the way its supposed to work.

Comment: I can't see how that is possible with `ActionLink`, as passing params in the url is by design. You may need to look into using ASP.NET MVC `Ajax.ActionLink` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: You can't use a link to pass data outside of the query string. You will need to make a form and submit that form or use an AJAX call.

Comment: You could technically store the data in cookies or web storage, but that would be bad design.

Comment: And what would be the point of not showing it anyway? The user can always type it in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a link in the end (i.e. ) then there is no way, because clicking on the link will make browser sent a GET request to a given URL and the only way to specify parameters is as part of the url.

If you still want to "hide" the id from the url, then make a POST request and send id in post body.

However I strongly **do not recommend** to go with POST, because it contradicts the HTTP requests convention where POST requests are for updating data.